# Number format to 1 decimal place

Tags: php, api, echo, number-formatting

I am getting 6 decimal places for when extracting insights from Facebook Api using the below command. Can someone please let me know how can I modify this command to get only 1 decimal place.

```
 echo '<td>'.$insight->cpm. '</td>';
```

Comment: `round($insight->cpm, 1)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`round`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php):

> Returns the rounded value of val to specified precision (number of digits after the decimal point).

```
echo '<td>' . round($insight->cpm, 1) . '</td>';
```

Comment: @Amit - If you haven't used php's round function before, you may wish to review the section on $mode at http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php since default php rounding may work differently than you expect.

Answer (score 2):

you should format the number first, as per requirement-

```
number_format($insight->cpm,1)
```

It will return string value containing one decimal place.

```
round($insight->cpm,1);
```

It will return float value containing one decimal place.